# Problem parsing xml in php

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I want to parse a xml, but it giving me a blank output.

My code:

```
$url = 'http://feeds.news.com.au/public/rss/2.0/fs_breaking_news_13.xml';
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
    $title = $xml->item[1]->title;
```

The $title, gives a blank output.

Plz help.

Thank you
Zeeshan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the file, it looks like you didn't see that the items are inside of a node named `<channel>`

```
$title = (string) $xml->channel->item[1]->title;
```

Comment: Dont know exactly, but as I remember children are always organized as lists, so you need to add a index to *channel* too ($xml->channel[0]->item[1]->title;)